# Referencing SQL Server columns dynamically in SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

SQL 2008

Hello,

I have a rather different task I have to do in SQL. It's a bit more involved than this, but I'm going to try to make it simple.

I need to somehow SELECT a column dynamically. Like this:

```
declare @ColName varchar(50)

select @ColName = 'Column1' --This is an actual column name in a real table called 'MyTable'

select @ColName from MyTable where Column2 = 123
```

Is there a way to do something like this? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the link in @SQLMenace answer!

```
declare @ColName varchar(50)
select @ColName = 'Column1'

declare @sql varchar(MAX)
select @sql = 'select ' + @ColName + ' MyTable where Column2 = 123'

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need dynamic SQL, but first read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to make sure you don't open yourself up for `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @colNameIn AS varchar(50) = 'Column1'

DECLARE @template AS varchar(MAX) = 'select {@ColName} from MyTable where Column2 = 123' -- This template can be expanded

-- Protect yourself from injection or invalid columns:
DECLARE @ColName AS varchar(50)
SELECT @ColName = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColNameIn

IF @ColName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS varchar(MAX)
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@template, '{@ColName}', QUOTENAME(@ColName))
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as using a CASE statement if you have predefined all of the acceptable column names in the procedure.

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(50)

SET @ColName = 'Column1'

SELECT CASE @ColName
         WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1
         WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2
       END
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column2 = 123
```